# Android SMS permission restriction

Tags: android, sms, android-permissions

Google has introduced a policy to restrict SMS/Call permission. https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9047303

It says: Apps that fail to meet policy requirements or submit a Permissions Declaration Form by January 9, 2019 may be removed from Google Play.

Does this mean that a binary distributed outside of the Play store won't be affected by these restrictions?

Answer (score 0):

> Does this mean that a binary distributed outside of the Play store won't be affected by these restrictions?

Correct. There is nothing in the OS that somehow enforces these restrictions. After all, Google themselves have no practical *technical* definition of "core functionality", relying instead upon documentation and marketing materials. If Google cannot define "core functionality", Android has no way to determine whether these permissions are part of that "core functionality".

So, if you distribute your app through other channels, you are not bound by this particular restriction, as it is a channel-imposed restriction, not an OS-imposed one. Those other channels might have their own restrictions, though.

---

Note that questions about app distribution channels [are generally considered to be off-topic here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272165/are-developer-centric-questions-about-application-stores-on-topic). I am trying to focus on the OS side of this subject. Just be careful with future questions!